# flask : rendering unicode instead of string

Tags: json, python-2.7, unicode, flask, python-unicode

i have a weird problem with rendering unicode , where it show unicode in browser but if i print it it will show me string

i'm using flask with flask-restful

here's my code

```
class Branch_worker_view_information(Resource):
    decorators = [Clients.auth.login_required]
    def get(self,Worker_id):
        View_Information = Branch_And_Worker.query.filter_by(id=Worker_id).first()
        if View_Information is None:
            abort(404)

        #import json
        #jstring = json.dumps(View_Information.Displayed_Name, ensure_ascii=False)


        print View_Information.Displayed_Name
        return View_Information.Displayed_Name#jsonify(Displayed_Name=View_Information.Displayed_Name, Type=View_Information.Type)
```

what happend is that in browser i got `"\u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0629 \u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0629"` 
and in my terminal

`تجربة تجربة
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2015 16:21:58] "GET /BOs/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

i've tried many solutions in stackoverflow but end up getting unicode

### **update**

i tried to use `make_response` it works great to render it as string
but when i tried to make it render json it would give me unicode instead of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will i have found a workaround , even though i believe it's not right way to do it

`charset=utf-8` made it work, anyway here's my code

```
response = """
{
    "Displayed_Name": "%s",
    "Type": "%s",
    "Lat":"%s",
    "Lon":"%s",
    "City":"%s",
    "Txt_Address":"%s",
    "Status":"%s"
}
        """%(View_Information.Displayed_Name,
             View_Information.Type,
        View_Information.Lat,
        View_Information.Lon,
        View_Information.City,
        View_Information.Txt_Address,
        View_Information.Status)


        to_be_returned= make_response(response)
        to_be_returned.mimetype='application/json;charset=utf-8'

        return to_be_returned
```

Comment: Did you try jsonify? You can import it from flask.

Comment: it's very strange. Because I didn't have any problems with jsonify and cyrillic characters. Could you give a small example of code that doesn't work and desirable output?